# MySQL DateTime between rows

Tags: mysql

I would like to calculate the time difference between 2 rows in my table.

The table is a basic table with ID and time:

```
Id_op Heure_deb             Id_act  Type      TIMEDIFF

OP1 2017-04-21 10:35:53 ACT4    Classique
OP1 2017-04-21 10:36:22 ACT3    Formateur
OP1 2017-04-21 14:44:13 ACT1    Classique
OP2 2017-04-21 14:43:54 ACT1    Classique
OP2 2017-04-21 14:44:08 ACT2    Classique
OP2 2017-04-21 14:44:30 ACT2    Classique
OP2 2017-04-21 14:44:34 ACT4    Classique
OP2 2017-04-24 09:11:57 ACT3    Classique
```

I know the function `lag()` but it doesn't work with MySQL...

Do you have a solution?

Comment: question is not sufficient update your desired output and for which column you want to get difference

Comment: OK sorry in fact this table controls the duration of some activity and I would like to calculate the time between 2 consecutive row. The date represente the start of this activity. The number of activity is not important just the time between consecutive row is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TIME_TO_SEC` followed by `TIMEDIFF()`

```
SELECT a.columns_to_select, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.Heure_deb, b.Heure_deb)) as Time_Difference
FROM basic_table a
LEFT JOIN basic_table b ON a.unique_column = b.unique_column
WHERE
a.id = some_value
AND
b.id = some_value
```

Comment: Thx but your solution work If my primary key is Id_op and Heure_deb ? I think the solution is with a left join, I do not master this

Comment: good practice is you should have a primary key for a table. if not compare all the values which you think as unique.